# How do I get Figma API to work with the Google App-script API?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, oauth, google-slides-api, figma-api

I am thinking of creating a google slides to Figma exporter using Google App Script. Starting out I would first like to route the shapes created in from google Slides to figma. How would I go about setting up my file? And I don't know how to set up the Oauth api communication between Google and Figma or if it's even possible.

I believe that I can start with:

## References

### Figma reference

https://github.com/figma/plugin-samples/blob/master/react/src/code.ts

### google app script reference

https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-samples/blob/master/slides/style/style.gs#L30

## Get Figma Shape

```
var file=projectid.key()
var=figma rectangle= file()

  await figma.loadFontAsync({ family: "Roboto", style: "Regular" })
name;


var figmaShape = {
figma.ui.onmessage = msg => {
  if (msg.type === 'create-rectangles') {
    const nodes = []    
        for (let i = 0; i < msg.count; i++) {
      const rect = figma.createRectangle()
      rect.x = i * 150
      rect.fills = [{type: 'SOLID', color: {r: 1, g: 0.5, b: 0}}]
      figma.currentPage.appendChild(rect)
      nodes.push(rect)
    }

    figma.currentPage.selection = nodes
    figma.viewport.scrollAndZoomIntoView(nodes)
  }

  figma.closePlugin()
}
};
```

## Get Google Docs File Shape

```
var powerpointfile = driveApp.getFileById = ("### Slide file ID ###")

function powerPointShape = () {
var slide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides()[0];
var shape = slide.insertShape(SlidesApp.ShapeType.TEXT_BOX, 100, 200, 300,
getObjectId.element(SHAPE);
                              };
```

## Create new Figma file#

```
file.getSlides.shape = (powerPointShape, ) => {
  this.powerPointShape.getRigh()=this.figmaShape(rect.x);
  this.powerPointShape.getleft()=this.figmaShape(rect.y);
}
```

But from there would I also want to get the file id from google app script to a Figma File?

and after looking at: https://github.com/alyssaxuu/figma-to-google-slides/blob/master/Chrome%20Extension/background.js I wonder if I would have to create a chrome extension or a google Slides plugin.

Comment: You would use [google-oauth](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2) to handle oauth.

Comment: @TheMaster At Figma, it seems that there are 2 methods for retrieving the access token. One is the use of the OAuth2 process. Another is the direct generation of the access token on the page that the user was logged in. The generated access token has no expiration time. [Ref](https://www.figma.com/developers/api#access-tokens) From this,. at my answer, I used the latter as a sample case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this answer?

### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, it seems that the shapes of Google Slides cannot be put to the page of Figma file. Because it seems that there are no methods of API for putting the shapes. But it was found that that the pages of Figma file can be retrieved as the image using Figma API.

In this answer, I would like to propose the sample script that the pages of Figma file can be put to the Google Slides as the image using Figma API with the access token. So you can directly use Figma API with Google Apps Script.

### Usage:

#### 1. Retrieve access token

You can see the method for retrieving the access token at [here](https://www.figma.com/developers/api#access-tokens). Although there is also OAuth2 for retrieving the access token, in your situation, I thought that the method for directly generating the access token on the site might be suitable. So in this answer, the generated access token on the site is used. Please retrieve the access token as follows.

> **Generate a personal access token**
>
> 1. Login to your Figma account.
> 2. Head to the Account Settings from the top-left menu inside Figma.
> 3. Find the Personal Access Tokens section.
> 4. Click Create new token.
> 5. A token will be generated. This will be your only chance to copy the token, so make sure you keep a copy of this in a secure place.

The access token is like `#####-########-####-####-####-############`. At Google Apps Script, the authorization is done by `headers: {"X-Figma-Token": accessToken}`.

#### 2. Retrieve file key

In order to retrieve the Figma file using Figma API, the file key is required. You can retrieve the file key from the URL of the file.

The URL of the file is like `https://www.figma.com/file/###/sampleFilename`. In this case, `###` is the file key.

#### 3. Run script

The sample script is as follows. Before you run the script, please set the variables of `accessToken` and `fileKey`.

```
function myFunction() {
  var accessToken = "###"; // Please set your access token.
  var fileKey = "###"; // Please set the file key.

  var baseUrl = "https://api.figma.com/v1";
  var params = {
    method: "get",
    headers: {"X-Figma-Token": accessToken},
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
  };
  var fileInfo = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(baseUrl + "/files/" + fileKey, params));
  var children = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(baseUrl + "/images/" + fileKey + "?format=jpg&scale=3&ids=" + fileInfo.document.children.map(function(c) {return c.id}).join(","), params));
  if (!children.err) {
    var s = SlidesApp.create("sampleSlide");
    var slide = s.getSlides()[0];
    var keys = Object.keys(children.images);
    keys.forEach(function(c, i) {
      slide.insertImage(children.images[c]);
      if (i != keys.length - 1) slide = s.insertSlide(i + 1);
    })
  } else {
    throw new Error(children);
  }
}
```

- When `myFunction()` is run, at first, the file information is retrieved with the file key `fileKey`. Then, all pages are retrieved from the retrieved file information, and the retrieved pages are put to each slide of new Google Slides.
- I think that the action of this script is similar to [the script](https://github.com/alyssaxuu/figma-to-google-slides/blob/master/Chrome%20Extension/background.js) which is shown at the bottom of your question.

### Note:

- This is a sample script. So please modify it for your actual situation.

### References:

- [Figma API](https://www.figma.com/developers/api)
- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)
- [Class SlidesApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slides-app)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: nice @Tanaike !!!!! You really only think I can get the images from Figma and send them to google slides? I will try this out and see if it works!

Comment: @Zachary Blumstein Thank you for replying. In the current stage, it seems that although the data of shapes and pages in Figma file can be retrieved with the API, the data of shapes and pages cannot be put to the Figma file using API. But such methods might be added in the future update. If you found the methods for achieving the latter when you read the document of API, please tell me. Also I would like to check it.

Comment: so what you're saying is "there is no way to convert a shape in google slides to an svg and then send it through to Figma?" I know Figma works with SVGs

Comment: @Zachary Blumstein Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, in the current stage, it seems that there are not methods for putting the data including SVG from outside to the page of Figma file in Figma API. I deeply apologize for this situation. When you read the document of API, if you find it, please tell me. If my answer was not useful for your situation, I have to apologize.

Comment: whoops it almost worked. however I got an error. `This app isn't verified

This app hasn't been verified by Google yet. Only proceed if you know and trust the developer.`

Comment: @Zachary Blumstein I think that the message is not error message. In this case, the script is still not run. When the message is shown in a opened dialog by running the script, please authorize the scopes for running the script on the dialog. By this, the script works. But if the variables of `accessToken` and `fileKey` are not correct, an error occurs when the script is run.

Comment: @Zachary Blumstein When `This app hasn't been verified by Google yet. Only proceed if you know and trust the developer.` is shown in a opened dialog by running the script, please click `Advanced`, and click `Go to ### (unsafe)` (`###` is the project name). Then, click `Allow` button. This means the authorization of the scopes for running the script. By this, the script is run.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202172/discussion-between-zachary-blumstein-and-tanaike).